# Postgresql function, multiple session safe

Tags: postgresql

I've a problem with postgresql function that is executed from multiple sessions. The function `foo` is created in multiple sessions at the exact same time. That causes the login function to be executed at the same time.

Inside the login function (see below) there is a if-statement `IF token does not exists THEN` that also is executed at the exact same time. Of course, it will be false for all the function since the token never has been created yet.

This is not the behaviour I want. Is it some how possible to make the `login` function being "thread-safe". Like synchronized in Java?

Pseudo function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$body$
BEGIN
    token = login();

    result = doStuffWithTheLogin(token);

    IF result = LoginFailed THEN
        token = login(true);
        RETURN 'RETRY';
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

The login function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login(forceReload BOOLEAN) RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$body$
BEGIN
    IF NOT forceReload THEN
        token = getTokenFromStorage();
    END IF;

    IF token does not exists THEN
        token = createNewToken();
        saveTokenToStorage(token);
    END IF;

    RETURN token;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

I've tried with table locks. But that didn't really do the job. The `login` function takes about 2-3 seconds to finish, if there is 100 foo tasks, the table will be locked for a long time.

Comment: "*The function foo is **created** in multiple sessions at the exact same time*" - why are you *creating* the same function over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what issue you're having or trying to solve, but it sounds like you're looking for an advisory lock:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

And perhaps exception handling:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

Comment: Advisory locks are probably the best way to go here.